# wasd swapped with arrow keys, FN + w not working to fix

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, fn-key

I know the basics of how to fix my pc but this is something I've never had happen: my wasd keys are swapped with arrow keys.

I tried <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> as that would fix it. However I believe the <kbd>FN</kbd> key was somehow disabled while away from my pc. I have tried unplugging the keyboard.

What else can I do?

Comment: Not much to go on, but have you tried toggling NumLock?

Comment: NumLock has function to it, but does not work in regards to fixing the keys it seems

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't press <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, when your <kbd>W</kbd> key is swapped. I would try <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem while i was playing Garry's mod. I Used <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

That worked for me, so I think it'll work for you.

If This Doesn't Work, Try <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>UPARROW</kbd>.